# beautiful soup find_all returning the None type

Tags: python, html, pip, path

im new to bs4 and thought trying to scrape the descrpitions of the main 9 [strawhat pirates](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Straw_Hat_Pirates#Main_Crew)(from luffy to brook) would be an ok way to practice what i know so far. but whenever i use find to get the  tag related to each pirate it returns none instead of the aside tag.

**input**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Straw_Hat_Pirates'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
straw_section = soup.find('table', 'cs StrawHatPiratesColors')
pirates = straw_section.find_all('div', class_ = 'Gallery-pic')
pirate_links=[pirate.a['href'] for count, pirate in enumerate(pirates) if count < 9]

def prt_crawler():
    for pirate_link in pirate_links:
        prt_response = requests.get( "https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki" + pirate_link)
        prt_soup = BeautifulSoup(prt_response.text, 'html.parser')
        prt_section = prt_soup.find('aside', class_ = 'portable-infobox pi-background pi-theme-CharBox pi-theme-StrawHatPiratesColors pi-layout-default')
        print(prt_section)
        print()

prt_crawler()
```

**output**

```
None

None

None

None

None

None

None

None

None
```

ive tried both lmxl and html.parser, neither seem to make a difference

i was expecting to get nine variations of this html code:

```
<aside role="region" class="portable-infobox pi-background pi-theme-CharBox pi-theme-StrawHatPiratesColors pi-layout-default">
<h2 class="pi-item pi-item-spacing pi-title" data-source="name">Monkey D. Luffy</h2>
<div class="pi-image-collection" data-source="image">
    <ul class="pi-image-collection-tabs">
        <li class="pi-tab-link pi-item-spacing current" data-pi-tab="pi-tab-0">
            <span class="pi-tab-label">
                Anime post-timeskip
                
            </span>
        </li><li class="pi-tab-link pi-item-spacing " data-pi-tab="pi-tab-1">
            <span class="pi-tab-label">
                Anime pre-timeskip
                
            </span>
        </li><li class="pi-tab-link pi-item-spacing " data-pi-tab="pi-tab-2">
            <span class="pi-tab-label">
                Manga post-timeskip
                
            </span>
        </li><li class="pi-tab-link pi-item-spacing " data-pi-tab="pi-tab-3">
            <span class="pi-tab-label">
                Manga pre-timeskip
                
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    
        <div class="pi-image-collection-tab-content current" id="pi-tab-0">
            <figure class="pi-item pi-image">
                <a href="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/6/6d/Monkey_D._Luffy_Anime_Post_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest?cb=20200429191518" class="image image-thumbnail " title="Anime post-timeskip">
                    <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/6/6d/Monkey_D._Luffy_Anime_Post_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/239?cb=20200429191518" srcset="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/6/6d/Monkey_D._Luffy_Anime_Post_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/239?cb=20200429191518 1x, https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/6/6d/Monkey_D._Luffy_Anime_Post_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/478?cb=20200429191518 2x" class="pi-image-thumbnail" alt="Anime post-timeskip" width="239" height="500" data-image-key="Monkey D. Luffy Anime Post Timeskip Infobox.png" data-image-name="Monkey D. Luffy Anime Post Timeskip Infobox.png">
                    
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
    
        <div class="pi-image-collection-tab-content " id="pi-tab-1">
            <figure class="pi-item pi-image">
                <a href="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/e/e5/Monkey_D._Luffy_Anime_Pre_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest?cb=20200124060150" class="image image-thumbnail " title="Anime pre-timeskip">
                    <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/e/e5/Monkey_D._Luffy_Anime_Pre_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/255?cb=20200124060150" srcset="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/e/e5/Monkey_D._Luffy_Anime_Pre_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/255?cb=20200124060150 1x, https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/e/e5/Monkey_D._Luffy_Anime_Pre_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/511?cb=20200124060150 2x" class="pi-image-thumbnail" alt="Anime pre-timeskip" width="256" height="500" data-image-key="Monkey D. Luffy Anime Pre Timeskip Infobox.png" data-image-name="Monkey D. Luffy Anime Pre Timeskip Infobox.png">
                    
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
    
        <div class="pi-image-collection-tab-content " id="pi-tab-2">
            <figure class="pi-item pi-image">
                <a href="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/d/d8/Monkey_D._Luffy_Manga_Post_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest?cb=20141011154302" class="image image-thumbnail " title="Manga post-timeskip">
                    <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/d/d8/Monkey_D._Luffy_Manga_Post_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/293?cb=20141011154302" srcset="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/d/d8/Monkey_D._Luffy_Manga_Post_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/293?cb=20141011154302 1x, https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/d/d8/Monkey_D._Luffy_Manga_Post_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/586?cb=20141011154302 2x" class="pi-image-thumbnail" alt="Manga post-timeskip" width="270" height="461" data-image-key="Monkey D. Luffy Manga Post Timeskip Infobox.png" data-image-name="Monkey D. Luffy Manga Post Timeskip Infobox.png">
                    
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
    
        <div class="pi-image-collection-tab-content " id="pi-tab-3">
            <figure class="pi-item pi-image">
                <a href="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/7/72/Monkey_D._Luffy_Manga_Pre_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest?cb=20210427074037" class="image image-thumbnail " title="Manga pre-timeskip">
                    <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/7/72/Monkey_D._Luffy_Manga_Pre_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/312?cb=20210427074037" srcset="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/7/72/Monkey_D._Luffy_Manga_Pre_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/312?cb=20210427074037 1x, https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/7/72/Monkey_D._Luffy_Manga_Pre_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/624?cb=20210427074037 2x" class="pi-image-thumbnail" alt="Manga pre-timeskip" width="270" height="370" data-image-key="Monkey D. Luffy Manga Pre Timeskip Infobox.png" data-image-name="Monkey D. Luffy Manga Pre Timeskip Infobox.png">
                    
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
    
</div>
<nav class="pi-navigation pi-item-spacing pi-secondary-background pi-secondary-font"><strong class="mw-selflink selflink">Introduction</strong> • <a href="/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy/Gallery" title="Monkey D. Luffy/Gallery">Gallery</a> • <a href="/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy/Personality" title="Monkey D. Luffy/Personality">Personality</a> • <a href="/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy/Relationships" title="Monkey D. Luffy/Relationships">Relationships</a> • <a href="/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy/Abilities_and_Powers" title="Monkey D. Luffy/Abilities and Powers">Abilities&nbsp;and&nbsp;Powers</a> • <a href="/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy/History" title="Monkey D. Luffy/History">History</a> • <a href="/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy/Misc." title="Monkey D. Luffy/Misc.">Misc.</a></nav>
<section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color pi-collapse pi-collapse-open">
    <h2 class="pi-item pi-header pi-secondary-font pi-item-spacing pi-secondary-background">Statistics</h2>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="jname">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Japanese Name:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">モンキー・<ruby lang="ja"><rb>D</rb><rp>（</rp><rt>ディー</rt><rp>）</rp></ruby>・ルフィ</div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="rname">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Romanized Name:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><i>Monkī Dī Rufi</i></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ename">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Official English Name:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Monkey D. Luffy</div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="first">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Debut:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><a href="/wiki/Chapter_1" title="Chapter 1">Chapter 1</a>;<sup id="cite_ref-First_of_All_1-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-First_of_All-1">[1]</a></sup> <a href="/wiki/Episode_1" title="Episode 1">Episode 1</a><sup id="cite_ref-Debut_2-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Debut-2">[2]</a></sup></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="affiliation">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Affiliations:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><ul><li><a href="/wiki/Straw_Hat_Pirates" title="Straw Hat Pirates">Straw Hat Pirates</a>;</li><li><a href="/wiki/Ninja-Pirate-Mink-Samurai_Alliance" title="Ninja-Pirate-Mink-Samurai Alliance">Ninja-Pirate-Mink-Samurai Alliance</a>;</li><li><a href="/wiki/Dadan_Family" title="Dadan Family">Dadan Family</a> (former);</li><li><a href="/wiki/Impel_Down" title="Impel Down">Impel Down</a> (former)</li></ul></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="occupation">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Occupations:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><a href="/wiki/Pirate" title="Pirate">Pirate</a>; <a href="/wiki/Captain" class="mw-redirect" title="Captain">Captain</a><sup id="cite_ref-Debut_2-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Debut-2">[2]</a></sup>; Prisoner (former); <a href="/wiki/Bandits" title="Bandits">Bandit</a> (former)</div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="residence">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Residence:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><a href="/wiki/Foosha_Village" title="Foosha Village">Foosha Village</a> (former); <a href="/wiki/Mt._Colubo" title="Mt. Colubo">Mt. Colubo</a> (former); <a href="/wiki/Rusukaina" title="Rusukaina">Rusukaina</a> (former)</div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="alias">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Alias:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><ul><li>Lucy<span style="font-weight: normal"> (<span class="t_nihongo_kanji" lang="ja">ルーシー</span><span class="t_nihongo_comma" style="display:none">,</span> <i><span class="t_nihongo_romaji">Rūshī</span></i><span class="t_nihongo_help"><sup><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Japanese" class="extiw" title="wikipedia:Help:Japanese"><span class="t_nihongo_icon" style="color:#00e;font:bold 80% sans-serif;text-decoration:none;padding:0 .1em;">?</span></a></sup></span>)</span><sup id="cite_ref-3" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-3">[3]</a></sup></li><li>Luffy-tarou<sup id="cite_ref-information_4-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-information-4">[4]</a></sup><span style="font-weight: normal"> (<span class="t_nihongo_kanji" lang="ja">ルフィ太郎</span><span class="t_nihongo_comma" style="display:none">,</span> <i><span class="t_nihongo_romaji">Rufitarō</span></i><span class="t_nihongo_help"><sup><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Japanese" class="extiw" title="wikipedia:Help:Japanese"><span class="t_nihongo_icon" style="color:#00e;font:bold 80% sans-serif;text-decoration:none;padding:0 .1em;">?</span></a></sup></span>, English version: "Luffytaro")</span><sup id="cite_ref-5" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-5">[5]</a></sup></li><li>Luffy-no-Umi<span style="font-weight: normal"> (<span class="t_nihongo_kanji" lang="ja">ルフィの海</span><span class="t_nihongo_comma" style="display:none">,</span> <i><span class="t_nihongo_romaji">Rufinoumi</span></i><span class="t_nihongo_help"><sup><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Japanese" class="extiw" title="wikipedia:Help:Japanese"><span class="t_nihongo_icon" style="color:#00e;font:bold 80% sans-serif;text-decoration:none;padding:0 .1em;">?</span></a></sup></span>)</span><sup id="cite_ref-6" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-6">[6]</a></sup></li></ul></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="epithet">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Epithet:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Straw Hat Luffy<span style="font-weight: normal"> (<span class="t_nihongo_kanji" lang="ja">麦わらのルフィ</span><span class="t_nihongo_comma" style="display:none">,</span> <i><span class="t_nihongo_romaji">Mugiwara no Rufi</span></i><span class="t_nihongo_help"><sup><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Japanese" class="extiw" title="wikipedia:Help:Japanese"><span class="t_nihongo_icon" style="color:#00e;font:bold 80% sans-serif;text-decoration:none;padding:0 .1em;">?</span></a></sup></span>)</span><sup id="cite_ref-Epithet_7-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Epithet-7">[7]</a></sup></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="status">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Status:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Alive</div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="age">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Age:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><ul><li>7 (debut);</li><li>17 (pre-timeskip)<sup id="cite_ref-9" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-9">[9]</a></sup>;</li><li>19 (post-timeskip)<sup id="cite_ref-10" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-10">[10]</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-11" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-11">[11]</a></sup></li></ul></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="birth">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Birthday:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">May 5th (Children's Day)<sup id="cite_ref-Birth_12-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Birth-12">[12]</a></sup></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="height">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Height:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><ul><li>91 cm  (2'11¾) (debut)<sup id="cite_ref-information_4-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-information-4">[4]</a></sup></li><li>172 cm (5'7¾") (pre-timeskip)<sup id="cite_ref-13" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-13">[13]</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-14" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-14">[14]</a></sup></li><li>174 cm (5'8½") (post-timeskip)<sup id="cite_ref-Birth_12-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Birth-12">[12]</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-15" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-15">[15]</a></sup></li></ul></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="blood type">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Blood Type:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">F<sup id="cite_ref-sbs66_8-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-sbs66-8">[8]</a></sup></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="bounty">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Bounty:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><ul><li><span style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Belly" title="Belly"><img alt="Beli.png" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAQAICTAEAOw%3D%3D" decoding="async" width="12" height="20" data-image-name="Beli.png" data-image-key="Beli.png" data-src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/d/de/Beli.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/12?cb=20141206091723" class="lazyload"></a></span>1,500,000,000<sup id="cite_ref-16" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-16">[16]</a></sup></li><li><span style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Belly" title="Belly"><img alt="Beli.png" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAQAICTAEAOw%3D%3D" decoding="async" width="12" height="20" data-image-name="Beli.png" data-image-key="Beli.png" data-src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/d/de/Beli.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/12?cb=20141206091723" class="lazyload"></a></span><s>500,000,000</s><sup id="cite_ref-c800_17-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-c800-17">[17]</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-c801_18-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-c801-18">[18]</a></sup></li><li><span style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Belly" title="Belly"><img alt="Beli.png" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAQAICTAEAOw%3D%3D" decoding="async" width="12" height="20" data-image-name="Beli.png" data-image-key="Beli.png" data-src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/d/de/Beli.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/12?cb=20141206091723" class="lazyload"></a></span><s>400,000,000</s><sup id="cite_ref-19" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-19">[19]</a></sup><br></li><li><span style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Belly" title="Belly"><img alt="Beli.png" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAQAICTAEAOw%3D%3D" decoding="async" width="12" height="20" data-image-name="Beli.png" data-image-key="Beli.png" data-src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/d/de/Beli.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/12?cb=20141206091723" class="lazyload"></a></span><s>300,000,000</s><sup id="cite_ref-c435_20-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-c435-20">[20]</a></sup></li><li><span style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Belly" title="Belly"><img alt="Beli.png" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAQAICTAEAOw%3D%3D" decoding="async" width="12" height="20" data-image-name="Beli.png" data-image-key="Beli.png" data-src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/d/de/Beli.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/12?cb=20141206091723" class="lazyload"></a></span><s>100,000,000</s><sup id="cite_ref-21" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-21">[21]</a></sup></li><li><span style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Belly" title="Belly"><img alt="Beli.png" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAQAICTAEAOw%3D%3D" decoding="async" width="12" height="20" data-image-name="Beli.png" data-image-key="Beli.png" data-src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/d/de/Beli.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/12?cb=20141206091723" class="lazyload"></a></span><s>30,000,000</s><sup id="cite_ref-22" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-22">[22]</a></sup></li></ul></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="jva">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Japanese VA:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayumi_Tanaka" class="extiw" title="wikipedia:Mayumi Tanaka">Mayumi Tanaka</a>,<br> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urara_Takano" class="extiw" title="wikipedia:Urara Takano">Urara Takano</a> (<a href="/wiki/One_Piece_-_Defeat_Him!_The_Pirate_Ganzack" title="One Piece - Defeat Him! The Pirate Ganzack">OVA</a>)</div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="Odex eva">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Odex English VA:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Chuck Powers</div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="4kids eva">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">4Kids English VA:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erica_Schroeder" class="extiw" title="wikipedia:Erica Schroeder">Bella Hudson</a></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="Funi eva">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Funi English VA:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colleen_Clinkenbeard" class="extiw" title="wikipedia:Colleen Clinkenbeard">Colleen Clinkenbeard</a></div>
</div>

</section>
<section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color pi-collapse pi-collapse-open">
    <h2 class="pi-item pi-header pi-secondary-font pi-item-spacing pi-secondary-background">Devil Fruit</h2>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="dfname">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Japanese Name:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><a href="/wiki/Gomu_Gomu_no_Mi" title="Gomu Gomu no Mi">Gomu Gomu no Mi</a></div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="dfename">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">English Name:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Gum-Gum Fruit</div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="dfmeaning">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Meaning:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Rubber</div>
</div>

<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="dftype">
    
        <h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Type:</h3>
    
    <div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><a href="/wiki/Paramecia" title="Paramecia">Paramecia</a><sup id="cite_ref-23" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-23">[23]</a></sup></div>
</div>

</section>
</aside>
```

Comment: What is the expected output ??

Comment: I dont know, but it seems that a / is missing in prt_response = requests.get( "https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki" + pirate_link)

Comment: @sushanth thanks i didnt think of putting it there. its updated now.

Comment: @Stefan i dont think so since one of the pirate links looks like this: '/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy'

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to find the element you want and go up in tags until you find a sequence you can use to get to the said element. In this case, there are only 69 elements that go from body to tr to the and from 9 to 17 are the ones you are looking for. Keep in mind that this is a quick and "dirty" way to do it, there could be a better way to solve the problem.

```
for i in range(9, 18):
    soup.select("tbody > tr > th")[i].text.strip()
```

Comment: wait where should i add that?

Comment: Anywhere under soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser'). That's all you really need to get all the 9 descriptions to be honest.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I wanted to do. I wanted to go in each of their specific web pages and scrape the part on the right side where you can see an image of the character and all the details of that character. sorry I think my using the word 'description probably threw you off.